# Published .Net-Core App won't run

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core

I published my app for Ubuntu in dotnet 2.1 using this command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -v ubuntu-x64
```

I have .net-core run-time on Ubuntu. when i want to run the executable in the directory it gives this error:

> an assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest ... was not found

but when i go to the publish directory and run the executable it works fine.
so my question is should I use the fault-free one in publish or there's an error I should fix?

EDIT (.NET CORE INFO FOR THE DEVELOPER MACHINE):

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   2.1.300 
>   Commit:    adab45bf0c
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.15063 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.300\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 2.1.0   Commit:  caa7b7e2ba
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     1.1.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.200 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0
>   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   1.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.7 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

EDIT (.NET CORE INFO FOR THE UBUNTU MACHINE):

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:   2.1.300 
>   Commit:    adab45bf0c
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     ubuntu  OS Version:  18.04  OS
>   Platform: Linux  RID:         ubuntu.18.04-x64  Base Path:
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 2.1.0   Commit:  caa7b7e2ba
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.1.300 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0
>   [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0
>   [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7
>   [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
>   [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Comment: Are you upgrading your app from .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: I think you are running a wrong command.  Try this: `dotnet publish -c Release -r ubuntu-x64`.

Comment: @WillHuang i used your command. Unfortunately nothing changed.

Comment: Can you share your `dotnet --info` output?

Comment: @WillHuang added as edit.

Comment: The **.NET Core 2.1**'s SDK version should be `2.1.300`.  You should update your .NET Core SDK first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You installed the wrong .NET Core Runtime/SDK.  You should [install the latest .NET Core 2.1 SDK or Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux) to run your .NET Core 2.1 application correctly.

- The .NET Core 2.1 SDK version number should be `v2.1.300`.
- The .NET Core 2.1 Runtime version number should be `v2.1.0`.

Comment: @AliSh Your `dotnet --info` looks like wrong.  Do you mean you can run the app in your development machine and can't run on your other Ubuntu machine?  Where are you run your `dotnet --info` command?

Comment: yes I can run it on the developer machine. and I also added the info from the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: In the error the path specified for the assemblies are in "lib/netcoreapp2.0/" or "lib/netstandard2.0/" but as I checked these folders don't exist!

Comment: @AliSh Can you captue a screenshot when you're doing `dotnet publish -c Release -v ubuntu-x64`?